# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException on 2008R2 Server

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I have a program that I want to run on a server which is able to monitor various servers on a network and send out email notifications when certain situations involving those servers occur.

Currently, I am able to run this program on my local machine, and have it fire off emails (using gmail SMTP).  However, when I try to run it on the server via the command prompt, it throws the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:587
```

The code related to the sending of the email is fairly simple:

```
static void sendEmail(MailAddressCollection mailCollection, string emailSender,
                      string emailDisplayName, string emailPassword,
                      string subject, string body) {

    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(emailSender, emailDisplayName);

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, emailPassword)
    };

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage {
        From = fromAddress,
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    };

    foreach (MailAddress mailAddress in mailCollection) {
        message.To.Add(mailAddress);
    }

    smtpClient.Send(message);

}
```

The server in question is a 2008R2 box, and it does not have Windows Firewall enabled.  Also, port 25 is definitely open, as this server can send other types of emails (specifically, those generated by a Dynamics CRM email router).

What could be causing this error?

Comment: "port 25 is definitely open" but the script is using smtp.gmail.com on port 587. So is port 587 open?

Comment: I am not sure how to check, but I tried "netstat -a" and I did not see port 587 in the list.  I did see port 25 though.

Comment: On the server, try using telnet. "telnet smtp.gmail.com 587" and see if you can connect.

Comment: I did the telnet test, and it failed too: "Connection to smtp.gmail.com...could not open connection to the host, on port 587: connection failed".

Comment: Then I'm guessing outbound port 587 is blocked at some firewall. Are you behind a corporate firewall? You mention Dynamic CRM can send emails, why don't you just use the same settings as Dynamic CRM to send your email?

Comment: I need to replicate this same program/monitoring tool on a different environment as well which does not have the same CRM email router.  So I was trying to use something generic like gmail in my code.  As for the firewall, this server is hosted with a generic cloud hosting provider, so I do not know how to get the details on any sort of firewall they would be imposing on us.  The Windows firewall is turned off though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to Gmail blocking the IP address of the server attempting to send email.

When attempting to send emails using a Gmail account, first attempt logging into Gmail manually on that machine specific at that specific IP address, using a browser.  I ultimately had to do this and go through the process of authenticating that the email send attempts from my server (being generated programmatically) were legitimate.  If you do not go through this process like I did, Gmail can assume that your server is not a legitimate email sender and can continue to assume all traffic from your IP address is invalid--until you formally validate that IP address as described above.